# Google calendar API returning different results than API explorer

Tags: python, django, api, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using the python client library to make a request to the Google Calendar API. It works fine, but I'm not getting all of the events on the calendar. However, if I view the API explorer, I get everything and in a different format. For example, the API explorer includes a "summary" key which I need. Why is that?

```
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_FILE_PATH, scopes)
http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())

calendar = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)

currentTime = datetime.datetime.now()
maxTime = currentTime + relativedelta(months=+1)

#do this to get all events on this day
maxTime = maxTime.replace(minute=59, hour=23, second=59)

currentTime = currentTime.isoformat('T') + '-06:00'
maxTime = maxTime.isoformat('T') + '-06:00'

response = calendar.events().list(calendarId="*******", singleEvents=True, maxResults=2500, showHiddenInvitations=True, timeMin=currentTime, timeMax=maxTime).execute()

return JsonResponse(response)
```

Answer (score 0):

All the properties that the Calendar API explorer can be found in [Resource representations](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource-representations) including "`summary`". Now to fetch all of that after a successful API request, be sure to specify `' * '` in your [q parameter](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) to tell Event.list that you want a complete response.